# print working and echo not working in php

Tags: php

The below code is working with only print statement

```
 file_exists('index.php') || print "hi"; \\ works fine and prints hi



 file_exists('index.php') || echo "hi";  \\ error
```

Why does `print` work but `echo` causes a parse error?

Comment: Were you denied to use old-plain `if`? The tricky code is never a good decision

Comment: While it *may* be somewhat clear what you're going for, this is not a question. Furthermore, it shows little research, as by reading the docs for both `echo` and `print` the answer would be reasonably straightforward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `echo` is a language construct and `print` is a built-in function.

Using `echo` is also slightly faster than `print` for the same reason, but causes a parser error when used inside an expression.

See also the bug report: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=15866

Answer (score 1):

I think this is beacuse print returns a boolean value while echo returns nothing, so you can't use in a boolean expression.

http://www.htmlite.com/php004.php

Comment: `parse_str` also doesn't return anything and yet can be used in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

print returns one, meaning true echo does not return anything. Looks like you have an or statment that needs both file_exists and the output to return true.

Answer (score 0):

Echo and Print seems similar but differ slightly

Print - 1
echo -Nothing

In the above statement if file exists then it shows nothing

if not exist then next step is OR Print ,Print always returns a Boolean value